# How do you do math operations on r.now()

Tags: rethinkdb

I am implementing an express session with rethinkdb and I have an 'expires' field that is calculated as so: r.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 (1 day from now).

Can I do something like this?

```
r.now().add(millisecondsToAdd)
```

There is no api documentations for this.
It will also be useful for querying.

Note: I am using the official Javascript driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that

```
r.now().add(24*60 * 60 * 1000)
```

However, it's second, not millisecond. So to add one one more day, it is:

```
r.now().add(24*60*60)
```

When you browser the API, `add` saying about time: https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/ruby/add/

```
time.add(number[, number, ...]) → time
```

`sub` works similar to `add` btw.